# how can i make field node stop evaluating as Null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list, nodes

How do I make the node "ahead" for the parameter "head" of the object stop equaling "Null" when I use .getNext() on it? I just get NullPointerException everytime

LinkedNode have parameters LinkedNode and E data.

```
package sets;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

class LinkedNodeIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

 private LinkedNode<E> ahead;
 private E data;

 public LinkedNodeIterator(LinkedNode<E> head) {
  ahead = head;
   data = ahead.getData();
 }

 public boolean hasNext(){
  boolean here = false;
  LinkedNode<E> currNode = this.ahead;
  if(currNode.getNext() != null) here = true;
   return (here);
 }
//othercode...
}
```

and

```
package sets;

public class LinkedNode<E> {
  private E data;
  private LinkedNode<E> next;

  public LinkedNode(E data, LinkedNode<E> next) {
   this.data = data;
   this.next = next;
  }

  public E getData(){
   return data;
  }

  public LinkedNode<E> getNext(){
   return this.next;
  }
}
```

Comment: please add the full source code for LinkedNode as well, or at least clarify getData(), getNext() methods.

Comment: I have just done that

Answer (score 0):

Given this program, and assuming there are no more methods which modify the `ahead` variable, the only possible way for the ahead to be null, is in its initialization: In other words, `ahead` is null only when parameter `head` is null.

I suggest you two things:

- Make sure there are no more methods modifying the `ahead` variable. One sure way to achieve this is declaring it as `final` (and also a good practice, too).
- Add an assert in the first line of the constructor:

```
     assert head!=null;
```

... and run your program with "java -ea" to enable assertions.